# Discrepancy between initial value and closed form solution of linear 2D SDE

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

[Kloeden Platen Schurz 1994](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540570745) states the linear 2D SDE:

$$dX_t = A X_t dt + B X_t dW_t$$

where $a=5$ and $b=0.01$ and

$$A = \Big( \begin{matrix} -a & a \\ a & -a \end{matrix} \Big)$$
$$B = \Big( \begin{matrix} b & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{matrix} \Big)$$

They give explicit solution

$$X(t) = X_0 \exp{\Big( \big(A - \frac{B^2}{2} \big) t + B W_t \Big)}$$

As an example starting point, they give $X_0=\big(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0\end{matrix}\big)$.  However, at $t=0$, $W_t=0$ and

$$\Big( \big(A - \frac{B^2}{2} \big) 0 + B 0 \Big) =
\Big( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \Big)$$

and 
$$\exp{\Big( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \Big)} =
\Big( \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix} \Big)$$

So

$$X(0) = X_0 \Big( \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix} \Big)
= \big(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0\end{matrix}\big) \Big( \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix} \Big) = \big(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 1\end{matrix}\big) \neq X_0
$$

Please help.  I should be able to choose any starting point for $X_0$ and then evolve it according to the SDE.  The given explicit solution seems wrong in this case.  Is it wrong or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The exponent of the zero matrix is the identity matrix.

Comment: That would imply that the log of the identiy matrix is the 0 matrix.  Python's NumPy package, for what it's worth, is giving back (1 1; 1 1) as the exponent of the 0 matrix.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Also Python's numpy is giving $\Big( \begin{matrix} 0 & -\infty \\ -\infty & 0 \end{matrix} \Big)$ as the log of the identity matrix.  Is that a bad choice?  Maybe I should put in a separate question for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pointed out in comments to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3545400/are-numpys-choices-for-log-of-identity-matrix-and-exponent-of-zero-matrix-corre?noredirect=1#comment7290838_3545400) that NumPy's exp and log are doing element-wise operations, which are incorrect in this case.  I should have been using SciPy's [expm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.expm.html) and [logm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.logm.html?highlight=logm#scipy.linalg.logm).