# Are NumPy's choices for log of identity matrix and exponent of zero matrix correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms, matrix-exponential

Python's NumPy gives

$$\log{\Big( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \Big)} = \Big( \begin{matrix} 0 & -\infty \\ -\infty & 0 \end{matrix} \Big)$$

and

$$\exp{\Big( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix} \Big)} = \Big( \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix} \Big)$$

Are these choices consistent and correct?  Are there multiple choices/solutions for these operations on matrices?

The code is:

```
np.log([[1,0],[0,1]])
array([[  0., -inf],
       [-inf,   0.]])

np.exp([[0,0], [0,0]])
array([[ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.]])
```

NOTE: It is pointed out in comments below that NumPy is obviously doing element-wise operations, which are incorrect in this case.  I should have been using [expm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.expm.html) and [logm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.logm.html?highlight=logm#scipy.linalg.logm).  I will close with answer below to this effect.

Comment: Looks like the functions are applied to each entry of the matrices. If you actually want exp/log of the matrix these are wrong.

Comment: I don't know NumPy, but usually $\exp(0)=I$.

Comment: As Dirk pointed out, whatever you're doing isn't computing the matrix exponential or log. As far as I know numpy doesn't have built-in functions for this, you can use [scipy.linalg.expm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.expm.html) for the matrix exponential and [scipy.linalg.logm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.logm.html) for the log though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pointed out in comments above that NumPy exp and log are doing element-wise operations, which are unintended in this case.  I should have been using [expm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.expm.html) and [logm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.logm.html?highlight=logm#scipy.linalg.logm).

Comment: I wouldn't say *incorrect*, rather *not intended*

Answer (score 2):

Numpy (and most other programming languages which allow you to do similar things, such as Matlab) applies the exp and log functions to each element of an array, i.e.

```
exp(np.array([[a, b], [c, d]])) = np.array([[exp(a), exp(b)], [exp(c), exp(d)]])
log(np.array([[a, b], [c, d]])) = np.array([[log(a), log(b)], [log(c), log(d)]])
```

This, along with the IEEE standard that `log(0)=-Inf` and `exp(-Inf)=0`, fits perfectly with your result.

---

Note that I wrote `log(0)=-Inf`, not $\log(0)=-\infty$. The two statements are not identical.

- The first statement, `log(0)=-Inf`, is a statements about values of variables in a computer program, and is correct.
- The second statement, $\log(0)=-\infty$, is a statement about real numbers, and is incorrect. $\log(0)$ is undefined.